# How to save html as doc file using StreamReader class in C#

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to save my html page as doc through C# and jQuery. It is working but the images that show on html is not showing doc after saving it. Here is my code:

jQuery code:

```
function submit() {
    var imageInByte = encodeURIComponent($('#cmpstamp').attr('src'));
    $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Agreement.aspx/submitAgreement",
            data: JSON.stringify({ AppId: getQueryString("appid"), agreement: $('.word-content').html()),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d == "Success") {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            }
        })
}
```

C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string submitAgreement(string agreement, string AppId)
{          
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Documents/ApplicationFile/" + AppId + "/myagreement.doc"), true))
    {
        string output = agreement + str;                            
        writer.Write(output);
        writer.Close();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: You’re just writing text into a file, it won’t suddenly turn into a Word document nor get any images from anywhere. You’ll need to use a proper tool for the conversion.

Comment: could you suggest me any tool

Comment: No, because software/library recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow. There is a sister site for those, but do check their help section for rules first and do a search